# How can I source specific functions in an R script?

Tags: r, rlang

I have a script with my most commonly used functions which I source at the top of most scripts. Sometimes I only want to get one of the functions in that script, but I don't know how to indicate that I only want one specific function. I'm looking for a function that is similar to the :: used to get a function inside a package. A reproducible example:

```
# file a.R

foo <- function() cat("Hello!\n")
bar <- function() cat("Goodbye!\n")

# End of file a.R

# file b.R

# Can't just delete all functions
fun <- function(x) print(x)
fun("It's so late!")
    
source("a.R")
foo()
    
fun("See you next time")
# End of file
```

I read the "source" help and it was unhelpful to me. The solution I currently have is to assign a variable at the start of the script with the functions loaded before, then set the difference with what was there after:

```
list_before <- lsf.str()

# content of file b.R

new_funcs <- setdiff(lsf.str(),list_before)
```

Then I can use `rm(list=new_funcs[-1])` to keep only the function I wanted. This is, however a very convoluted way of doing this and I was hoping to find an easier solution.

Comment: put this all in a package?

Comment: Potentially useful for this task: https://github.com/klmr/box

Comment: For what it's worth @BGranato, I'm using that lsf.str() solution. Thanks for that

Comment: Happy it helped @Andreas :)

Answer (score 1):

A good way would be to write a package but it requires more knowledge (not there myself).

A good alternative I found is to use the package [**box**](https://github.com/klmr/box) that always you to import functions from an R script as a module.

You can import all functions or specific functions.

To set up a function as a module, you would use the roxygen2 documentation syntax as such:

```
#' This is a function to calculate a sum
#' @export
my_sum <- function(x, y){
x + y
}

#' This is a function to calculate a difference
#' @export
my_diff <- function(x, y){
x - y
}
```

Save the file as an R script "my_module.R"

The export parameter in the documentation tells **box** that what follows is a module. Then you can call box to reach a specific function in the module named "my_module".

Let's say your project directory has a *script* folder that contains your scripts and modules, you would import functions as such:

```
box::use(script/my_module)
my_module$my_sum(x, y)
```

***box::use()*** creates an environment that contains all the functions found inside the module.

You can also import single functions like as follows. Let's assume your directory is a bit more complex as well where modules are inside a *box* folder inside *script*.

```
box::use(./script/box/my_module[my_sum])
my_sum(x, y)
```

You can use box to fetch functions from packages as well. In a sense, it is better than calling **library()** that would import all the functions in the package.

Using box, you can organize script by objectives or whatever organization you have in place.
I have a script to deal with strings from which I fetch function that work with strings.
I have a script for plot functions that I use in my projects...etc

Answer (score 0):

`insertSource()` would help.
In your example, let's presume we need to import foo() from a.R :

```
# file b.R
foo <- function(){}
insertSource("a.R", functions = "foo", force=T)
foo <- foo@.Data
```